# Streams and wrappers: Romote FTP download

Tags: ftp, stream, wrapper

I'm using FTP to download remote files:

```
readfile("ftp://".$ftp_user.":".$ftp_pass."@".$ftp_host."/".$file);
```

But when I host the same code on different Linux web hosts (I tested 4), some can do it, some not. The remote file is hosted on another Linux web host.

I test the wrappers they support, the results are different, but all include "ftp":

```
print_r(stream_get_wrappers());

Array
(
    [0] => php
    [1] => file
    [2] => data
    [3] => http
    [4] => ftp
    [5] => compress.zlib
    [6] => zip
)

Array
(
    [0] => compress.zlib
    [1] => compress.bzip2
    [2] => dict
    [3] => ftp
    [4] => ftps
    [5] => gopher
    [6] => http
    [7] => https
    [8] => imap
    [9] => imaps
    [10] => pop3
    [11] => pop3s
    [12] => rtsp
    [13] => smtp
    [14] => smtps
    [15] => telnet
    [16] => tftp
    [17] => php
    [18] => file
    [19] => data
    [20] => zip
)
```

The first host can do it, the second not.

I am wondering where is problem. Please help, thanks

Comment: Firewall issues? PASV v.s active?

Comment: could you explain a little more what do you mean by "some can do it, some not"? any errors you see that may be worth sharing? :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out that allow_url_fopen is enabled in php.ini.